# Training loss decreases very fast after few epochs

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, training, loss

I am implementing an ANN whose training loss is in Figure:

[image: training loss]

As you can see training loss decreases very fast and it is approximately 3.2 at epochs 2, 3, ..., 8, ... 10, and so on. (batch learning)

The diagram is similar even though I increases MAX_EPOCHS to 2000.

Is it correct?

Note that my training set is a toy:

```
X = np.asmatrix([
        [2, 5, 3.2, 7.2],
        [1, 0.8, 1, 8.5],
        [2, 7, 3, 1.4]
    ])

targets = np.asarray([0,2,1])
targets = np.asmatrix(np.eye(np.max(targets) + 1)[targets])  # 1-hot
```

And I am using Gradient Descent with momentum

Comment: What is the architecture  of your ANN? The dataset seems extremely small (with only 3 samples) so it is difficult to explain the behaviour of the ANN. It is possible that with the given architecture and this dataset, the loss cannot be reduced beyond 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loss is converging fast simply cause you're totally overfitting on you're toy input samples, which is good, at least it proves that your training script works.

Comment: Thank you. I was using the toy samples for that purposes, indeed.